# NuxtJS pass context, store, inject and axios to plugin

Tags: javascript, axios, nuxtjs

As my question suggests, I want pass the $axios, context, store and inject functionality to a plugin I writing that integrates with `axios` and `auth0`.

I am getting this error...

```
Cannot read property 'authUrl' of undefined
```

with this code...

```js
export default ({ $axios }, context, store, inject) => {
const auth = $axios.create({
  baseURL: context.env.authUrl,
  headers: {
    Accept: store.$auth.$storage._state[`_token.auth0`],
    Authorization: `application/vnd.api+json`,
  }
});
}
```

I imagine it is the way the parameters are being passed to the function? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you create a plugin, you write it in the form

```js
export default ({ store, $axios }, inject) => {
  // access store or $axios directly
})
```

or

```js
export default (context, inject) => {
  // here you have context.store or context.$axios
})
```

See here for reference https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins

Please be aware that the order in which you set your plugins in `nuxt.config.js` could affect the availability of injected plugins inside the context: if axios plugin is inserted **after** your custom plugin, you could not be able to use axios itself in it.

However, the Axios module for nuxt has some interesting helpers that could be useful (see https://axios.nuxtjs.org/helpers)